# Opening a Report based on two date values on a form if they exist

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form (`frmReports`) that has two unbound textboxes which are used to enter dates.  One is FROM, one is TO.
These are used to filter out a report (`rptAllCommissions`).  If there are values in the textboxes, it filters.  If there aren't, or if there's one date and not both, it creates a WHERE statement for opening the report.  Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmdCommissions_Click()
    Dim strDateFrom As String
    Dim strDateTo As String
    Dim strWhere As String

    Const strcJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"

    strDateFrom = "[ClosingDate]"

    If IsDate(Me.txtFrom) Then
        strWhere = "(" & strDateFrom & " >=" & Format(Me.txtFrom, strcJetDate) & ")"
    End If
    If IsDate(Me.txtTo) Then

        If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
            strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
        End If

        strWhere = strWhere & "(" & strDateFrom & " <= " & Format(Me.txtTo + 1, strcJetDate) & ")"
    End If

    If CurrentProject.AllReports("rptAllCommissions").IsLoaded Then
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptAllCommissions"
    End If
    Debug.Print strWhere

    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptAllCommissions", acViewReport, strWhere

Exit_Handler:
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
        MsgBox "Error" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Cannot Open Report!"
    End If
    Resume Exit_Handler

End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is no matter what I try, the report never filters the records based on the WHERE statement created by the above routine.  Trying debugging, it outputs: 
If two dates are entered: `([ClosingDate] >=#04/01/2019#) AND ([ClosingDate] <= #05/25/2019#)`
If one date is entered: `([ClosingDate] >=#05/13/2019#)`

That seems right to me, but it's not filtering.  What the heck am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I should give credit the person who wrote the original routine, but I can't for the life of me find where I got it.  Sorry!  But whoever it was that originally wrote the routine, THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WhereCondition should be the 4th argument in the OpenReport method. You have it in the FilterName argument's spot.

[OpenReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openreport)

Comment: If only all our problems were this simple!